# Why is my page content loading before my header script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, deferred

`assets/javascript/hdr.js`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     console.log("testtt");
     function returnT() {
          return true;
     }
});
```

`functions.php`:

```
function hdr_scr() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'h_scr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'assets/javascript/hdr.js', array(), false, false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hdr_scr' );
```

`https://mypage.com/my-pos (TwentyTwenty Child: pos Template (my-pos.php))`:

```
    ...
    <!-- toward bottom of template -->
    <script>
        debugger;
        var t = returnT();
    </script>
    </div> <!-- end container...... -->

</main><!-- #main -->
```

The above scripts/page are as it is setup in my site. The issue I am coming across is, `var t = returnT();` is called even before the `console.log("testtt");` in my `hdr.js` file. That is causing an error.

Based on my setup, the page should have `hdr.js` content ready, for the page to invoke but for some reason it's not happening.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your code waits for **DOM** to be loaded, and then executes, because:

- `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` is the most used form for executing code when the DOM is ready
- `$(function() { ... })` is equivalent to the previous (it's a shorthand)
- `jQuery(function($) { ... })` it's a "safe" version of the same thing ($ is available inside the function, no matter what it was set before)

So, your code executes

```
var t = returnT();
```

before

```
jQuery(function($) {
  console.log("testtt");
  function returnT() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

so the `returnT()` function does not exist at the time you call it.

Either move the `returnT()` so it doesn't "wait" for DOM to be ready, or set the function call to wait for DOM ready too.

Comment: I haven't coded JS in over a couple of months and I totally blanked out!!! The calling method needs to also wait for DOM to be loaded, DUH!!! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I jumped the gun there... I added the caller to wait for DOM to be ready but it still fails... hmmmmmm... weird

Comment: Any error messages? Did you check that the function is really in the header?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: verify_lang is not defined`. Yes, the `hdr.js` is inside the `head` tag.

Comment: What is `verify_lang`? It seems that it's another `ReferenceError` (not the one you posted here)

Comment: Sorry, `verify_lang` is `returnT`. That's another function that is having the same issue.

Comment: I fixed it by moving the function outside of the `jQuery` ready function. So weird but it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm happy that I could at least assist :D you solved it in the end :)

Comment: Thanks! Also it just hit me that I can do the same thing in PHP so no JS was needed! But i just needed for someone to knock me with a hammer before my brain started working lol.